# Force/coerce evaluation of closure signature

Tags: rust

Here is a contrived example of what I am trying to do:

```
use std::boxed::Box;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo<'a>(pub &'a str);

pub trait IntoBox {
    fn into_box<'a>(self) -> Box<Fn(Foo) -> String>;
}

impl<B> IntoBox for B where B: Fn(Foo) -> String + 'static {
    fn into_box(self) -> Box<Fn(Foo) -> String> { Box::new(self) }
}

fn direct_into_box<B: Fn(Foo) -> String + 'static>(b: B) -> Box<Fn(Foo) -> String> {
    Box::new(b)
}

fn main() {
    // Doesn't work
    let x = IntoBox::into_box(|i| format!("{:?}", i) );

    // Works
    let y = IntoBox::into_box(|i: Foo| format!("{:?}", i) );

    // Also works
    let z = direct_into_box(|i| format!("{:?}", i) );
}
```

How do I get my trait impl to do the same evaluation of the closure as is done by my `direct_into_box`? I would have expected `direct_into_box` and my trait impl to behave in the same way.

The error on `x`:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <[closure@<anon>:20:31: 20:53] as std::ops::FnOnce<(Foo<'r>,)>>::Output == std::string::String`
  --> <anon>:20:13
   |
20 |     let x = IntoBox::into_box(|i| format!("{:?}", i) );
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime
   |
   = note: concrete lifetime that was found is lifetime '_#29r
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoBox` for `[closure@<anon>:20:31: 20:53]`
   = note: required by `IntoBox::into_box`

error[E0281]: type mismatch: the type `[closure@<anon>:20:31: 20:53]` implements the trait `std::ops::Fn<(_,)>`, but the trait `for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(Foo<'r>,)>` is required (expected concrete lifetime, found bound lifetime parameter )
  --> <anon>:20:13
   |
20 |     let x = IntoBox::into_box(|i| format!("{:?}", i) );
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoBox` for `[closure@<anon>:20:31: 20:53]`
   = note: required by `IntoBox::into_box`
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get it to run in the playground. What output did you get?

Comment: I was having issues with the playground earlier also. I've added the error output to my question.

Comment: so you don't get the error with the direct_into_box? grrr... don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like [an inference bug in the compiler](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24680). What seems to happen is that the compiler implements `Fn(Foo<'x>)` *for one specific lifetime `'x`* instead of `Fn(Foo<'a>)` *for any lifetime `'a`* on your closure.

Let's see if we can replicate the error by defining a struct by hand (this requires a nightly compiler), so we can better understand what's going on. First, let's define the struct the correct way:

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

// Foo and IntoBox unchanged

struct Func;

impl<'a> FnOnce<(Foo<'a>,)> for Func {
    type Output = String;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (Foo<'a>,)) -> String {
        self.call(args)
    }
}

impl<'a> FnMut<(Foo<'a>,)> for Func {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: (Foo<'a>,)) -> String {
        self.call(args)
    }
}

impl<'a> Fn<(Foo<'a>,)> for Func {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, (i,): (Foo<'a>,)) -> String {
        format!("{:?}", i)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = IntoBox::into_box(Func);
}
```

This `Func` struct compiles fine and behaves just like your original closure.

Now, let's break it:

```
impl FnOnce<(Foo<'static>,)> for Func {
    type Output = String;

    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (Foo<'static>,)) -> String {
        self.call(args)
    }
}

impl FnMut<(Foo<'static>,)> for Func {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: (Foo<'static>,)) -> String {
        self.call(args)
    }
}

impl Fn<(Foo<'static>,)> for Func {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, (i,): (Foo<'static>,)) -> String {
        format!("{:?}", i)
    }
}
```

What I've done here is that I've removed the `<'a>` on each `impl`, so that the impls are no longer generic over a lifetime, and I've replaced `Foo<'a>` with `Foo<'static>`. This means that now, the traits are only implemented when the "closure"'s argument is a `Foo<'static>`.

This fails to compile with the following errors:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `for<'r> <Func as std::ops::FnOnce<(Foo<'r>,)>>::Output == std::string::String`
  --> <anon>:51:13
   |
51 |     let x = IntoBox::into_box(Func);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected bound lifetime parameter , found concrete lifetime
   |
   = note: concrete lifetime that was found is the static lifetime
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoBox` for `Func`
   = note: required by `IntoBox::into_box`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'r> Func: std::ops::Fn<(Foo<'r>,)>` is not satisfied
  --> <anon>:51:13
   |
51 |     let x = IntoBox::into_box(Func);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `for<'r> std::ops::Fn<(Foo<'r>,)>` is not implemented for `Func`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
   = help:   <Func as std::ops::Fn<(Foo<'static>,)>>
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `IntoBox` for `Func`
   = note: required by `IntoBox::into_box`
```

The first error is the same, but instead of an internal name like `'_#29r`, the compiler mentions the static lifetime, because that's what I used here. I *suspect* that what the compiler is doing with the closure that doesn't compile in your code is similar to my second set of impls, just that instead of `'static`, it's some other concrete lifetime that we can't name in Rust. The second error is different but means pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Should your impressive writeup be added to / used to create a new issue?

Comment: Sure, if there's not already an issue about this problem yet (I didn't search thoroughly, which is why I linked to an issue search page :P), otherwise maybe it can be added to an existing issue.

Comment: @FrancisGagné, thanks for the detailed explanation! Thanks also for the link to the issue search—I looked around a little bit and I think [Incomprehensible error message when inference fails for closure](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24680) and [Incorrect lifetime inferred for closure](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/26937) describe my issue here. Edit: actually the latter may not be exactly the same issue, but seems related.

Comment: [Added a comment on issue 24680](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24680#issuecomment-260486263) with my analysis. Also edited the link in my answer to link directly to issue 24680.